# Add field to post form

Tags: customization

I have read [this](http://www.barbaralerici.net/creare-custom-post-avanzato-collegarlo-agli-articoli-wp/) tutorial to create forms da compilare per inserire delle schede di Film in un sito, fin quì ok. Ora vorrei fare in modo che quando scrivo una news con Wordpress, possa avere la possibilità di scegliere quale delle schede create linkare e/o mostrare sotto la notizia che ho scritto...﻿

I read this tutorial to create custom forms to insert films in a database. Now I want that when I write a post in wordpress, I can quickly link the forms below the news.

**CUSTOM FORM**
Image
Film title: Hercules
Release Date: xx/xx/xx

**NEWS**
*Here the text of my news*
*Here the custom form link associated to the the post*

Comment: Magic Field plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable writing plugins, you can use "meta boxes" to add custom meta fields to the post form. Please have a look at the [add_meta_box examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Examples) to see what I mean. The general idea is that you add a meta box containing a field, and save it to the meta table when the form is submitted.